# Is there a numerical definition or explanation about the meaning of those words related to time, such as `immediately`, `right now`, `recently`?

Tags: meaning

Is there a numerical definition or explanation about the meaning of those words related to time, such as `immediately`, `right now`, `recently`?

For example, `immediately` would be a range from 1 second to 10 minutes, imagine your boss ask you do something `immediately`, how long would you let him to wait to get started?

Comment: Depends on you what kind of boss you have. But seriously, it depends entirely on context. In evolution, "immediately after" typically could be millennia; in electronics and communication, it may be nanoseconds. In general English, it's "with no intervening X" -- the X being variously interpreted as another activity, or a spell of time.

Comment: No, there is no numerical definition. I would say it partly depends on the size of the task you have been asked to carry out. "Can you bring me that document immediately?" = you go straight to his office. "Can you start that project immediately instead of next month as we planned?" = you prepare to start work today.

Comment: It may help to carefully study the definitions of the words to understand implication and usage.